# Building docker where does `RUN mkdir` create a directory - cannot find it when running container

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and I'm building the docker file below using `docker build -t control .` It builds successfully with no errors specifically it says that it makes the `control` directory. Then I try to run the image with `docker run control` but it gives an error saying that it can't find `control/control_file/job.py`

Where does docker create the `control` directory. Is it in a container that I cannot see? As I can't see it being create anywhere and I'm unsure how to debug?

```
FROM python:2
RUN pip install requests\
&& pip install pymongo

RUN mkdir control

COPY control_file/ /control

ENV PYTHONPATH="/control:$PYTHONPATH"
RUN export PYTHONPATH=/control:$PYTHONPATH

CMD ["python","/control/job.py"]
```

This is the directory structure:

```
├── control_file
│   ├── insert_to_container.py
│   ├── ip_path
│   ├── job.py
│   └── read_info.py
└── Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The `job.py` is now in `/control` within your Docker build.

With the `COPY` command you copy all contents within `control_file/` into the new directory `/control`.

Change the last line to:

```
CMD ["python", "control/job.py"]
```

Comment: Schwarzl thanks for that. I've updated my question with the tree structure and I made your modification. It now says `python: can't open file 'insert_to_container.py':` . It is something simple but i cannot identity which path is wrong. The actual project is on git [link]https://github.com/ANRGUSC/DRUPE/tree/master/Docker_DCP/Resource_Profiler/Resource_Profiler_control_docker[link]

Comment: `job.py` calls `insert_to_container.py` I've include the code in my original post.

Comment: That's because `python` doesn't have the new directory `control/` in it's `sys.path` and therefore cannot locate the files within.

Comment: Schwarzl I've updated my Dockerfile in the original question. Am I correctly adding the `/control` directory to the PYTHONPATH?  when I print `sys.path` in the container it is not listed. Can't figure out why :(

Comment: please update your question with the current result of `for p in sys.path: print(p)`

Answer (score 0):

you docker file has mistakes, please find below correct one  and control_file directory should available in build directory (where you building docker image )....job.py should have execute permission

```
FROM python:2
RUN pip install requests\
&& pip install pymongo
RUN mkdir -p /control/control_file
COPY control_file/ /control/control_file
CMD [ "python" , "/control/control_file/job.py" ]
```